# Commonmark -> CommonMark typo in automated CommonMark migration

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown, spelling, automatic-edits

Common**m**ark -> Common**M**ark typo in automated CommonMark migration

[image: in a]

Example from https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/157697/revisions

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on one of my own answers.

Comment: Flagging as no longer reproducible since the migration is now complete.

Comment: @pppery This request can still stand. It's possible (and done before) that the team can retroactively fix these edit summaries in the database.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog When before did that happen, out of curiosity?

Comment: @pppery It was done retroactively on all rollbacks once - those used to say "Rollback to revision [x]" (lowercase "revision") but now say "Rollback to Revision [x]" (with "Revision" capitalized).

Comment: Rollbacks are already a weird case; they say "rollback to revision 12" in the page history, "rolled back to a previous revision" in the user activity page, and "rollback to [GUID] in the reopen review queue"